# Switching the hands of the clock

Tags: local-time

Let us switch the positions of the minute hand and the hour hand of a calassic clock with only 12 hours, not 24. Note that most of the time we will end up with an absurd configuration. But are there any valid such configuratins? If *yes*, count the number of *valid* configurations.

Till now i got only one configuration, 12:00. 
I considered 2 cases, if the clock is indicating a whole hour time, except 12:00, then it is a sure absurdity, because the hour hand will not directly point toward the time panel. Similar argument when it shows x:30. So i got only one solution 12:00. But still i am uncertain whether i have missed any and would like to know them and how ae any other solutions possible.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are obviously also all the tines (11 of them) when the two hands coincide. But answers to the linked question identify more.

Comment: I suggest answerers answer the linked question.